# Update list adapter from another class

Tags: android, kotlin

I am developing my first application in kotlin, and I have encountered the following problem:

I have a "RecyclerView" in my activity with a method of updating it

```
class GroupsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

val TAG = "GroupsActivity"


companion object {
    var active: Boolean = false

    var tableModel: List<GroupModel>? = null

}

fun updateList() {

    rv_list.adapter = GroupsListAdapter(this, tableModel)

}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_groups)

    if (WebSocketConnection.connected) {
        print(1)
    }

    rv_list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    rv_list.hasFixedSize()

    rv_list.adapter = GroupsListAdapter(this, tableModel)


}
}
```

The list will be updated asynchronously from another class at any time. This is the method:

```
fun jsonActionCheck(action : String, jsonString: String){

    val gson = Gson()

    when (action){
        "LOGIN_OK" -> {}
        "LOGOUT" -> {}
        "GET_GROUPS" -> {

            val jsonModel : JsonGroups = gson.fromJson(jsonString, JsonGroups::class.java)

            if(GroupsActivity.active){

                GroupsActivity.tableModel = jsonModel.data

                GroupsActivity.updateList()
            }
        }
        "GET_CHAT_LIST" -> {}
        "SEND_MESSAGE" -> {
            //var grp = model.data.get(0).group
            //var msg = model.data.get(0).message
        }
        "GET_MESSAGE" -> {}
        else -> {}
    }
}
```

I know that the method is not static being out of companion object, but from inside I can not reference the list.

Comment: Have you tried interface and delegate to update Datasource of RecyclerView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Interface

Write Interface and implemented it at GroupsActivity
Something like this

```
/**
 * View Call Back interface for Activity
 */
interface ViewCallBackOperations : BaseViewOpration {

    fun onDataReceived(randomDialog: List<MovieModel>)

    fun onError(error: String)
}
```

Implemneted interface at Activity and override callback method, something like this

```
class PopularFragment : Activity(), PopularMVPContract.ViewCallBackOperations,
```

Override method for an interface, these methods will get called asynchronously from another class as I am getting data from the Internet from Web API for my application

```
    override fun onDataReceived(randomDialog: List<MovieModel>) {
    adapter!!.updateData(randomDialog)
}

override fun onError(error: String) {
    this.showSnackBar("Oops !! Something went wrong please try again !!")
}
```

## Another class

This is another class from where these methods get called

```
    private fun handlePopularResponse(data: JSONObject?, error: String?) {
    if (null == error && null != mViewCallBack) {
        val gson = Gson()
        val recentMoviesResponse: RecentAPIResponse = gson.fromJson(data.toString(), RecentAPIResponse::class.java)
        mViewCallBack!!.get()!!.onDataReceived(recentMoviesResponse.data)
    } else if (null != mViewCallBack){
        mViewCallBack!!.get()!!.onError(error!!)
    }
}
```

## mViewCallBack - what is this?

This is nothing but weakreference object of activity, initialised using the constructor, something like this

```
private var mViewCallBack: WeakReference<PopularMVPContract.ViewCallBackOperations>? = null

init {
    mViewCallBack = WeakReference(viewCallBackOperations)
}
```

## Adapter Class

Declaration of List Object:

```
private var movieList: MutableList<MovieModel> = mutableListOf<MovieModel>()
```

Add a method in adapter class like following

```
 fun updateData(data: List<MovieModel>) {
    movieList.clear()
    movieList.addAll(data)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve what you want by following this steps:

```
-take list from adapter object. ( e.g. adapterObj.list)
-clear list. (e.g. adapterObj.list.clear)
-add new list in adapter list. (e.g. adapterObj.list.addAll(newlistObj))
```